# Quickly get a list of all svn:externals for a remote svn repository

Tags: svn

We have an svn repository with lots of directories and files and our build system needs to be able to find all of the svn:externals properties, recursively for a branch in the repository, before checking it out. Currently we use:

```
svn propget svn:externals -R http://url.of.repo/Branch
```

This has proved extremely time consuming and is a real bandwidth hog. It appears that the client is receiving all of the props for everything in the repo and doing the filtering locally (though I haven't confirmed this with wireshark). Is there a faster way to do this? Preferably some way of getting the server to only return the desired data.

Answer (score 30):

As you mentioned, it does consume network bandwidth. However, if you have access to the server where those repositories are hosted, you may run it via `file://` protocol. It is proven to be faster and not network consuming.

```
svn propget svn:externals -R file:///path/to/repo/Branch
```

Also, if you had the entire working copy in place, you may also run it within your WC.

```
svn propget svn:externals -R /path/to/WC
```

Hope it helps you to achieve the results faster!

Comment: Unfortunately, our build system doesn't have direct access to the SVN servers, so this doesn't get us past the problem, but I'm upvoting your answer because it really is a good solution if you have that sort of access.

Comment: I'm using SVN Server 1.4.6 and using the `file://` will give me *Aborted* after a few seconds. Similar to http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2007-04/0500.shtml

Comment: Using the file:// protocol in a system where there are more than 1 user is dangerous and not recommended, due to the inadequacy of the file locking.

Answer (score 4):

not sure where I found this gem, but it is quite useful to see the **externals with own externals**:

```
Windows:
    svn status . | findstr /R "^X"

Linux/Unix:
    svn status . | grep -E "^X"
```

Answer (score 3):

I finally came up with a solution. I decided to break up the request into multiple small svn requests and then make each of those a task to be run by a thread pool. This kind of slams the svn server, but in our case the svn server is on the LAN and this query is only made during full builds so it doesn't seem to be an issue.

```
import os
import sys
import threading
import ThreadPool

thread_pool = ThreadPool.ThreadPool(8)
externs_dict = {}
externs_lock = threading.Lock()

def getExternRev( path, url ):
    cmd = 'svn info "%s"' % url
    pipe = os.popen(cmd, 'r')
    data = pipe.read().splitlines()

    #Harvest last changed rev
    for line in data:
        if "Last Changed Rev" in line:
            revision = line.split(":")[1].strip()
            externs_lock.acquire()
            externs_dict[path] = (url, revision)
            externs_lock.release()

def getExterns(url, base_dir):
    cmd = 'svn propget svn:externals "%s"' % url
    pipe = os.popen(cmd, 'r')
    data = pipe.read().splitlines()
    pipe.close()

    for line in data:
        if line:
            line = line.split()
            path = base_dir + line[0]
            url = line[1]
            thread_pool.add_task( getExternRev, path, url )

def processDir(url, base_dir):
    thread_pool.add_task( getExterns, url, base_dir )

    cmd = 'svn list "%s"' % url
    pipe = os.popen(cmd, 'r')
    listing = pipe.read().splitlines()
    pipe.close()

    dir_list = []
    for node in listing:
        if node.endswith('/'):
            dir_list.append(node)

    for node in dir_list:
        #externs_data.extend( analyzePath( url + node, base_dir + node ) )
        thread_pool.add_task( processDir, url+node, base_dir+node )

def analyzePath(url, base_dir = ''):
    thread_pool.add_task( processDir, url, base_dir )
    thread_pool.wait_completion()


analyzePath( "http://url/to/repository" )
print externs_dict
```

Comment: I have problem with the `os.popen()` when executed in a thread. It just dies silently. I gave up running it in a thread and removed all of the threading part from this script. Though I'm sacrificing the speed here, this script is more reliable as compared to `propget -R` which just die silently when a repository is too big.

Comment: The version that doesn't use ThreadPool https://gist.github.com/ceilfors/741d8152106a310dd454

Answer (score 0):

It is slow because of the -R switch; all directories within your repository path are searched for the property recursively, which is a lot of work.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out why it does it, but was just wondering if anyone had a faster way. It's not looking promising though.

Comment: I think it is that simple: if you need to do it recursively, it just will be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal solution (may have side-effects) and not answer on your problem, but

You can rewrite all externals definitions and add (rewritten) in one common, known place - this way you'll eliminate recursion in pg after change

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Python and the pysvn library, here is a complete command line program I'm using for SVN externals:

```python
"""
@file
@brief SVN externals utilities.
@author Lukasz Matecki
"""
import sys
import os
import pysvn
import argparse

class External(object):

    def __init__(self, parent, remote_loc, local_loc, revision):
        self.parent = parent
        self.remote_loc = remote_loc
        self.local_loc = local_loc
        self.revision = revision

    def __str__(self):
        if self.revision.kind == pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number:
            return """\
Parent:     {0}
Source:     {1}@{2}
Local name: {3}""".format(self.parent, self.remote_loc, self.revision.number, self.local_loc)
        else:
            return """\
Parent:     {0}
Source:     {1} 
Local name: {2}""".format(self.parent, self.remote_loc, self.local_loc)


def find_externals(client, repo_path, external_path=None):
    """
    @brief Find SVN externals.
    @param client (pysvn.Client) The client to use.
    @param repo_path (str) The repository path to analyze.
    @param external_path (str) The URL of the external to find; if omitted, all externals will be searched.
    @returns [External] The list of externals descriptors or empty list if none found.
    """
    repo_root = client.root_url_from_path(repo_path)

    def parse(ext_prop):
        for parent in ext_prop:
            external = ext_prop[parent]
            for line in external.splitlines():
                path, name = line.split()
                path = path.replace("^", repo_root)
                parts = path.split("@")
                if len(parts) > 1:
                    url = parts[0]
                    rev = pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, int(parts[1]))
                else:
                    url = parts[0]
                    rev = pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.head)
                retval = External(parent, url, name, rev)
                if external_path and not external_path == url:
                    continue
                else:
                    yield retval

    for entry in client.ls(repo_path, recurse=True):
        if entry["kind"] == pysvn.node_kind.dir and entry["has_props"] == True:
            externals = client.propget("svn:externals", entry["name"])
            if externals:
                for e in parse(externals):
                    yield e


def check_externals(client, externals_list):
    for i, e in enumerate(externals_list):
        url = e.remote_loc
        rev = e.revision
        try:
            info = client.info2(url, revision=rev, recurse=False)
            props = info[0][1]
            url = props.URL
            print("[{0}] Existing:\n{1}".format(i + 1, "\n".join(["   {0}".format(line) for line in str(e).splitlines()])))
        except:
            print("[{0}] Not found:\n{1}".format(i + 1, "\n".join(["   {0}".format(line) for line in str(e).splitlines()])))

def main(cmdargs):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="SVN externals processing.",
                                     formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                                     prefix_chars='-+')

    SUPPORTED_COMMANDS = ("check", "references")

    parser.add_argument(
        "action",
        type=str,
        default="check",
        choices=SUPPORTED_COMMANDS,
        help="""\
the operation to execute:
   'check' to validate all externals in a given location;
   'references' to print all references to a given location""")

    parser.add_argument(
        "url",
        type=str,
        help="the URL to operate on")

    parser.add_argument(
        "--repo", "-r",
        dest="repo",
        type=str,
        default=None,
        help="the repository (or path within) to perform the operation on, if omitted is inferred from url parameter")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    client = pysvn.Client()

    if args.action == "check":
        externals = find_externals(client, args.url)
        check_externals(client, externals)
    elif args.action == "references":
        if args.repo:
            repo_root = args.repo
        else:
            repo_root = client.root_url_from_path(args.url)
        for i, e in enumerate(find_externals(client, repo_root, args.url)):
            print("[{0}] Reference:\n{1}".format(i + 1, "\n".join(["   {0}".format(line) for line in str(e).splitlines()])))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

This should work in both Python 2 and Python 3.
You can use it like this (actual addresses removed):

```
python svn_externals.py references https://~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/cmd_utils.py
[1] Reference:
   Parent:     https://~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/BEFORE_MK2/scripts/utils
   Source:     https://~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/tools/python/cmd_utils.py
   Local name: cmd_utils.py
[2] Reference:
   Parent:     https://~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/VTB-1425_PCU/scripts/utils
   Source:     https://~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/tools/python/cmd_utils.py
   Local name: cmd_utils.py
[3] Reference:
   Parent:     https://~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/scripts/utils
   Source:     https://~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/tools/python/cmd_utils.py
   Local name: cmd_utils.py
```

As for the performance, this works quite fast (although my repository is quite small). You have to check it for yourself.